# How do I make an exact ajax request from the following form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, multer

I have the following form :

```
<form action = "/upload-file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group" style="display: inline; float:left;">
        <input type="file" (change)="submit($event)" name = "pic" style="margin-top: 10%;">
      </div>
</form>
```

On the server side I'm using multer to catch the file and store it. While using `upload.single('pic');` works prefectly fine if I try to submit this form ( `event.srcElement.form.submit()` in the submit function ), I can't seem to get the exact same result with an ajax call.

I have tried :

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/upload-file',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'file',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: files,
        success: function (datat) {
            console.log('success');
            return false;
        }
```

But mutler doesn't seem to accept it. How do I set the fieldname of the file and such? Or how do I make jQuery submit the same exact thing as the form would've but without refreshing/redirecting the page?

This is how the file looks from a successful form submit :
[image: File Description]

***Edit:***

The upload needs to have the 'pic' fieldname , otherwise `upload.single('pic')` won't accept it. That's what I think I need to figure out how to set.

Comment: 5 seconds of googling gave me this: http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax. Note the `FormData()` function which I believe is part of the DOM API and not specifically related to jquery.

Comment: @slebetman I did found that and followed it a bit before posting the question. I did also found out that `The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".` Still not really sure why would I use it to send only 1 file. Also the server in the tutorial isn't using multer which only seems to accept files sent from a tag with a specific name.

Comment: Can you show what your `files` variable looks like that you're submitting as the `data` value in the ajax call?

Comment: @user1640736: You don't need to use `FormData()` if you want to just send values of regular inputs. But you need to use it if you want to send a file via ajax. There is no direct access to the content of the file selection input because that would be a security risk. Imagine any website being able to download your /etc/passwd file when you visit or being able to download your keychain database. It's the reason the file selection box is so restrictive and browsers do not allow you to have arbitrary file I/O on the user's machine. The user himself must deliberately upload only the file he intend

Comment: @Chase `files` is simply `event.srcelement.data.file` or something like that.